# URL Rewrites of categories that have subcategory don't work

Tags: category, url-rewrite, magento2.4.2

**Normal behavior:** All URL rewrites of categories work.

**What I am getting:** Categories that have subcategories do not work. But categories that have no subcategory work fine.

**What I tried:**

- Used Oleg Kowal URL rewrites to regenerate them all. (deleted all URL rewrites before that).
- Disabled all custom extensions.

Didn't work.

**What I suspect:** I think Magepow categories extension messed it somehow in the database. But, no way to tell if it is the case.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Are the categories anchor set to yes ?

Comment: Thanks, that did something. Now 1st level categories work, 2nd level don't and last level works.

Comment: Try changing theme to blank or luma to see if it from some customization, if not try disabling also custom module to find which one is the problematic.